# How to add Carousal images in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

how to add these images in carousal in flutter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this [carousel_slider 4.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package from pubdev.

Installation

Add carousel_slider: ^4.0.0 to your pubspec.yaml dependencies. And import it:

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
```

How to use
Simply create a CarouselSlider widget, and pass the required params:

```
CarouselSlider(
  options: CarouselOptions(height: 400.0),
  items: [1,2,3,4,5].map((i) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber
          ),
          child: Text('text $i', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),)
        );
      },
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator you can use this for dot animation along with https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider here is a little example please adjust size accordingly

```
class Carosel extends StatelessWidget {
  List<listScreen> introduction = [
    listScreen(image: 'assets/Reading_Plans.png'),
    listScreen(image: 'assets/Reading_Plans.png'),
    listScreen(image: 'assets/Reading_Plans.png'),
    listScreen(image: 'assets/Reading_Plans.png'),
  ];
  set index(value) => _index.value = value;
  get index => _index.value;
  final _index = 0.obs;
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                child: CarouselSlider(
                  carouselController: _controller,
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                      enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                      viewportFraction: 1,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                      aspectRatio: 1.0,
                      onPageChanged: (ind, reason) {
                        index = ind;
                      }),
                  items: introduction
                      .map((listScreen item) => Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: kToolbarHeight / 2,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage(item.image),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              // Spacer(),
                            ],
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 35.0,
                  vertical: 15,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Obx(() {
                      return index != 3
                          ? Container(
                              width: 90,
                              child: AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                                activeIndex: index,
                                count: 4,
                                effect: ExpandingDotsEffect(
                                  dotHeight: 13,
                                  dotWidth: 13,
                                  activeDotColor: Color(0xff5C5C78),
                                ),
                              ),

                          : Container();
                    }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct and fully functional. You can use

```
carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
```

or simply follow the following link to get a complete understanding of code.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEMx2ax0734&t=279s